# How can I get a scheduled task to run for a user regardless of which computer the user is logged onto?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

I've got a scheduled task that needs to run for a user at a specific time. However, the user sometimes logs onto one machine, the next day onto another, then next week onto yet another. At some pint during the day, the user might have to log onto another machine.

How do I get the scheduled task to run regardless of which computer the user is using?

I could of course create the task on all computers, but that seems a bit overkill. Running a script on log on (or a group policy) to create the task doesn't seem a good method either. Any ideas? Basically I want the scheduled task to be defined on the user instead of on the computer. If in the end I need to choose between the two options above, which is best?

Comment: So you want to run the scheduled task for the user on whichever computer the user happens to be logged on to?

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled tasks will run at their scheduled time regardless of whether the user is logged on interactively or not (unless you've got the 'run only if logged on' option set).

Does the task have to be run on the machine that the user is logged into? If so, why? There may be a better solution than a scheduled task.

Comment: We have a timekeeping program that is from the point of view of the user an intranet site and the requirement is that a browser window with is opened both at logon and at some time in the afternoon (for some users four o'clock, for some some other time). Another thing is a user who needs to send an email once every week, but needs to edit it before sending (an outlook window appears at a schedule with some attachment and subject prefilled, but the recipients and body are filled by the user since they vary more or less randomly)